# C and MIPS assembly code are not equivalent and I'm not sure why

Tags: c, assembly, mips

The C code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x[] = {3, 10, 4, 25, 33, 6, 2, 0};

int main(){
    int total = 0;
    int *pointer = x;
    while (*pointer != 0) {
        if (*pointer < 10)
            total = total + *pointer;
        pointer++;
    }
    printf("The total of things less than 10 is %d\n", total);
}
```

which produces the output `The total of things less than 10 is 15`, as it should.

These are the variable name changes I made for the MIPS assembly:

```
total    -> t0
pointer  -> t1 
*pointer -> t2
10       -> t3
```

The MIPS assembly I have right now, which doesn't work:

```
    .data
x:  
    .word 3, 10, 4, 25, 33, 6, 2, 0
text:
    .asciiz "The total of things less than 10 is "
newline:
    .asciiz "\n"

    .text
main: 
    li $t0, 0
    la $t1, x
    li $t3, 10
    j while
while:
    lw $t2, 0($t1)
    beq $t2, $0, done
    blt $t2, $t3, update
    addi $t1, $t1, 4
    j while
update:
    add $t0, $t0, $t2
done:
    la $a0, text
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    move $a0, $t0
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    la $a0, newline
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

I just don't see how they aren't equivalent. Can someone help?

Comment: What do you think happens after the `add $t0, $t0, $t2`?  There's no jump, so execution goes on with `la $a0, text` and printing the output.  I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: If you are thinking the presence of the label `done:` in between changes that: it does not.  Labels serve only as targets for jumps and branches.  They are not instructions, and by themselves they do not modify program flow in any way.  Execution "falls through" a label as if it were not there (since as far as the CPU is concerned, there isn't anything "there").

Comment: For the same reason, your `j while` a few lines above is a waste of an instruction, since `while` is exactly where execution would continue if you omitted the jump.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I thought the branch would be finished, and then continue. I suppose I could add a `continue:` within `while` and `j continue` in `update`. But suppose I wanted to do many `blt` conditionals. Would I have to do `continue1:`, `continue2:`, etc. in the while, or is there a better way?

Comment: I doubt there is ever a situation where I need to do that many conditionals though, or any way around it. Probably MIPS assembly is just "wordier" than C in that way. Thanks for your help, by the way.

Comment: Simple control flow error, easy to do in assembly: miss some control flow that is implicit in C/higher level languages.  Also happens with if-then nested within for-loop: e.g. increment of for loop only happens on one path of the if-then, but should happen on all paths after the if-then/if-then-else.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Nate Eldredge, I see that when `update` is reached, it just goes directly to printing with no jump. Therefore, the new code I've written that works is:

```
    .data
x:  
    .word 3, 10, 4, 25, 33, 6, 2, 0
text:
    .asciiz "The total of things less than 10 is "
newline:
    .asciiz "\n"

    .text
main: 
    li $t0, 0
    la $t1, x
    li $t3, 10
    j while
while:
    lw $t2, 0($t1)
    beq $t2, $0, done
    blt $t2, $t3, update
    continue:
        addi $t1, $t1, 4
        j while
update:
    add $t0, $t0, $t2
    j continue
done:
    la $a0, text
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    move $a0, $t0
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    la $a0, newline
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: You could simplify the loop logic by scheduling the pointer increment right after the load.  That would also be more efficient, putting it in the load delay slot.  Then `blt $t3, $t2` forward over an add, to implement `if (10 > tmp) total += tmp;` idiomatically.  Then the bottom of the loop can be `bnez $t2, while`, like the bottom of a `do{}while(tmp != 0)` loop.  It's ok to do `total += tmp` when `tmp=0` because `0` is the additive identify; it doesn't change the value.